# How and when is 做 used as the verb "to be"?

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs

Can someone please clarify how and when 做 is used to mean "to be" e.g.

> 不愿做奴隶人们

I am familiar with 做 meaning "to do" or "to make", and I would expect that if I was saying "I am a slave", “我是一个奴隶“ would be preferable to “我做一个奴隶“

Why is 做 used in the first instance?

Comment: In my short experience with chinese, I've seen 做 used as *to do* in terms of work or activity, so maybe slavery is considered as such, and then, instead of *being*  a slave, in chinese you say *do slavery (as an activity)*

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%81%9A I think this wiktionary page can explain something~ 做: 1. work, make; 2. act

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"做" has a meaning of "充当，担任" (serves as, work as) (from 现代汉语词典 Modern Chinese Dictionary). It is different from "是" (to be).

The nuance of English and Chinese here is a little different. In Chinese, we don't say "I don't want to be [a slave]" (我不愿是[奴隶]). It is always "I don't want to serve as (become, etc.) a slave" (我不愿做(成为)奴隶).

Answer (score 4):

做 also means '(to) do' in 不愿意做奴隶的人们, you can try to translate it like this: the folks who don't want to do a slaver('s job).

Another example:

> 我长大之后要做医生
>   I want to [be a doctor]/[do a doctor's job] when I grow up.

做 means some kind of action, while 是 means it's a state.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, 做 means "to function as."
不愿做奴隶人们 means, "I don't want to function as (do the role of) a slave."

The idiomatic English expression would be "I don't want to BE a slave."

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add some more examples.  If you're like me, it takes more than one example to get a non-superficial understanding.

#### To be [some role]

> 永远**做**人民的保护神!<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1655317617037927711&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> Forever **be** the people's guardian angel
>
> **做**老师简直太难了!<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1644107166459016004&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> **To be** a teacher [is] simply difficult!
>
> 别再花钱去理发店**做**造型了!<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1641851537491721240&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> Don't again spend money going to the hairdressers **to be** a model
>
> 射手座真的适合**做**爱人吗?<sup>[[src]](https://new.qq.com/omn/20181127/20181127A0FAF0.html)</sup>
> Is [a] Sagittarius really suitable **to be** a lover?

#### To be a [something]

> 其实我不想**做一个**虚伪的人<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1655432078010242289&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> In fact, I don't want **to be a** hypocritical person
>
> 如何**做一个**人见人爱的好媳妇?<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1655167794780327190&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> How **to be a** loved-by-all good daughter-in-law?
>
> 别胡思乱想了，**做一头**猪吧<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1648071594019681679&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> Don't let your imagination run wild, [and] **be a** pig
>
> 在故宫**做一只**猫，是什么样的一种感受?<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1655228519330488200&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> In the Forbidden City, **to be a** cat, is what kind of feeling?
> (Or: What does it feel like **to be a** cat in the Forbidden City?)

#### Cannot be [some role]

> **做不成**男女朋友 可以**做**兄妹吗?<sup>[[src]](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/2059192329719390827.html)</sup>
> [If we] **cannot be** boyfriend and girlfriend, can we **be** older brother and younger sister?
>
> 为什么**做不成**恋人，也**做不成**朋友?<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1650087057648199172&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> Why [we] **cannot be** sweethearts, [and] also **cannot be** friends
>
> **做不了**自己的主人,就会成为别人的道具<sup>[[src]](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/d8f4d181ce84b9d528ea81c758f5f61fb63628e7.html)</sup>
> [If you] **cannot be** your own master, [you] become another person's prop

#### Cannot be a [something]

> 是什么阻止了你,**做不成一个**勤俭持家的人?<sup>[[src]](http://www.sohu.com/a/243471373_100221664)</sup>
> What is preventing you; **cannot be a** hardworking housekeeping person?
>
> 你注定**做不成一只**树懒<sup>[[src]](http://qikan.cqvip.com/Qikan/Article/Detail?id=34608973)</sup>
> I am destined **to not be a** sloth
>
> 572巴士车上,我**做不了一只**[独立特行](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%89%B9%E8%A1%8C%E7%8B%AC%E7%AB%8B/10771165)的猪?<sup>[[src]](http://bbs.tianya.cn/post-41-733043-1.shtml)</sup>
> On the 572 bus, I **cannot be an** independent-behavior pig.