# How does "do" (做) mean "become" (成)?

Tags: meaning, characters

In the sentence ‘I want to be[come] a policeman’, why is the verb for ‘become’, ‘do’?

> 我想做一个警察。
>
> Wǒ xiǎng zuò yīgè jǐngchá.

I have seen one of the dictionary definitions of 做 to mean ’become’, but this is only after coming across this sentence. I have not heard of 做 meaning anything other than ‘do’ with many expansive concepts related to it, and have only heard of 成 to mean ‘become’.

Therefore, my question is twofold. Why use 做 instead of 成 - what is the difference in meaning? And, how does the word 做 as a singular character have such a broad meaning from ‘doing’ to ‘becoming’ without the addition of another character (e.g. 做出)? Meaning, the two concepts, though perhaps related, are quite distant without adding additional meaning (e.g. 自 or something). So, what is the background that causes this contextual meaning?

Comment: Related: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1209/19184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"做" contains the meaning of  "be ", not "become"

"我想**做**一个警察" means "I want to **be** a police"

it is "成为" that means "become", not just "成"

(*成 is mostly used as a result complement for varieties of verb*)

"我想**成为**一个警察" means "I want to **become** a police"

> *how does the word 做 as a singular character have such a broad meaning from ‘doing’ to ‘becoming’ without the addition of another character*

As I stated, 做 can mean 'be' but not 'become'

You know when does it mean 'be' or 'do' by looking into the context.
When the object after 做 is a task or action, you know 做 means 'do'; When the object after 做 is an identity, you know 做 means 'be'

Example:

做功課，做木工，做好事 = do homework, do woodwork, do good thing (功課，木工，好事 are all nouns for action)

做學生，做木匠，做好人 = be a student, be a carpenter, be a good person (學生，木匠，好人 are all nouns for identity)

*Notice: don't confuse 做(do/ be) with 造(make), e.g. 做個包子 (be a bun) is not the same as 造個包子 (make a bun)*

Comment: 做個包子 - very funny.

Comment: Maybe you were kidding, but looking "做个包子" up on Google brings on pages about making buns, and not well, being a bun.

Comment: They all mistakenly used   做  instead of  造

Comment: @ MiCl It could be worse, for example, you wanted to write "我要努力做人" (I want to work hard in life being a man) but wrote "我要努力造人" (I want to work hard on making people) instead.  The latter implies you want to make love often so that you can have  babies.

Comment: Very interesting. I’ve learned wrong. Life is a lie.

Comment: @mic 做个包子 could interpret either way based on context. 做 can mean 'cook', like 做饭. 做个包子 can mean "cook a bun" in the context: 你今天中午要做点什么吃？我要做个包子. But it could be interpreted as you want to be a bun in other context. It all depends on how you use it.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel 做个包子 can mean "cook a bun" as well.

Comment: If there's room for  interpretation, I think "造包子" should be the preferred  term for 'make bun'. Why bother guessing "做包子" mean be a bun or make bun?

Comment: @TangHo 造包子 sounds odd. I don't hear people around ever say it. It should be either蒸包子 or 做包子.

Comment: 造包子 is not something you would find in standard Mandarin, I think. Is that how you say it in Cantonese?

Comment: Make bun in Cantonese is 整包,  製包 or  造包

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel 老师：小明，你长大后想做什么？小明：我长大后想做包子！

Answer (score 3):

I might ask a child: 你长大想做什么？

The child might answer:

我想做一个警察。or
我想当一个警察。or
我想成为一名警察。

Why do words have more than 1 meaning? People give words meanings!

做個包子 be a wimp is not the same as make a steamed bun 造個包子.

A bun in the oven is something else entirely!

Comment: 做个包子 can mean "cook a bun", compared to 做饭，做吃的，etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same, of course, as how we'd say it in English, but this is Mandarin after all. The trick is in trying to too-closely associate the English and Mandarin words in the *conventional* ways of speaking in the two languages, and that just doesn't work. The use of "做", meaning to "do" or to "perform", actually *does* make a lot of sense when you think of it this way:

> In this context, "做" means "*to perform the duties of*" or "*to do the work of*".

警察 is a societal role and, hence, it is defined by the performance of certain duties or activities and you are stating a desire to commence the performance of those activities.

To more explicitly translate not just the "gist" but the underlying *cognition* behind this:

> 我想做一个警察

into English words of the closest possible meanings and with proper grammar, it would look like

> "I desire (想) to do/perform [the work/duties of] (做) [one (一) instance (个) of] a police officer (警察)"

where items in [] are implied/optional in one or the other language. Hence, making it cleaner,

> "I desire to take up the mantle of and perform the duties involved in being a police officer."

A less verbose expression of the same thing and, perhaps more natural to an English speaker, may be

> "I would like to act in the capacity of a police officer."

so finally

> "I want to be a police officer."

at maximal concision though, of course, we can condense even further in casual talk:

> "I wanna be a cop!"

:)